# Not able to understand passport's serializeUser, DeserializeUser and GoogleStategy

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
    User.findById(id, function(err, user){
    done(err, user);
  });
});

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
 
  clientID:process.env.CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret:process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
  callbackURL:"http://localhost:3000/auth/google/secrets",
  userProfileURL:"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo"
  },
  
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done){
    console.log(profile);
    User.findOrCreate({googleId: profile.id}, function(err, user){
      return done(err, user);
    });

}));
```

Hi, I am learning web dev authetication and this code snippet is driving me crazy.
two questions.

1. why is "return" introduced at the end of the code(line 22) and why isn't it there in serialize and deserializeUser?
2. what is the difference between null and err, can they be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 1):

Callback doesn't replace `return` statement, for example, if your code would be as follows:

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
 
  clientID:process.env.CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret:process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
  callbackURL:"http://localhost:3000/auth/google/secrets",
  userProfileURL:"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo"
  },
  
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done){
    console.log(profile);
    User.findOrCreate({googleId: profile.id}, function(err, user){
    if(err){
      done(err, user); // it works
      }
    done(null,user) // it also works  
    });

}));
```

If we wouldn't use `return` in the `if` condition both error and success operations **will work**. Therefore, we use a `return` statement to **terminate** the current execution of the function and go on next step.

`err` is set to `null` because there is no possibility of error in the `serializeUser` function. Because this function works after passport authentication. If there is a problem with authentication, this function will not work without it.

Your `deserializeUser` function logic can be better as follows:

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
    User.findById(id, function(err, user){
    if(err){  return done(err) }; // when an error occur during the databese interaction
        if(!user){return done(null,false)} //there is no error but user wasn't found
        return done(null,user);//when user is found and there no error
  });
});
```

there is a possibility of error in the deserialization function. Any error can occur from a database, for which we must pass the error back.

Summary:

1. We always have to use `return`  and **terminate** function execution if we want to return something when **some condition** happened
2. `null` indicates that no error occurred here `done()`, if the error is likely to occur, you must return the error.

Comment: thanks for the solution. but, what is the diff. in the meaning of deserializeUser() of urs vs mine?

Comment: technically no difference, but you may want to act something when some certain condition happens for example when the user wasn't found or when an error happens